# ! method does not maintain newline in Scala

Tags: scala

I need to execute script using scala. when i execute Seq using ! the String after new line is lost. That is "Here is the" string gets updated to Jira and the other part of string after new line is lost. As i understand this is due ! not maintaining new line. Can anyone suggest how can i solve this ? See the code below.

```
import scala.sys.process._

val fileContent: String = """ Here is the 

text with 

new line """

Seq("/opt/atlassian-cli-2.6.0/atlassian.sh", "jira", "--action", "updateIssue", "--issue", "JIRA-2",  "--field", "customfield_10664" ,"--values", fileContent).!
```

Comment: What is the ! method? I get this error when trying to use it: error: value ! is not a member of Seq[java.lang.String]

Comment: This is process launching. I added the relevant import, it gives `implicit def stringSeqToProcess(command: Seq[String]): ProcessBuilder`

Comment: i.e. `import scala.sys.process._`

Answer (score 7):

As you can see from the snippet below, `!` maintains newlines just fine. It might be a problem with the script you are calling?

```
scala> Seq("echo", """hello
     |  world""").!
hello
 world
res5: Int = 0
```